# Static MAC addresses for EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mac-address

Is there a way to have the MAC addresses of an EC2 instance fixed?

Some software requires a static MAC address for licensing. How can this be overcome?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Recommended way to have "fixate" MAC address is adding `Elastic Network Interface` to `EC2` instance.

`ENI` is like an additional network card that have fixed IP address (internal and external) and fixed MAC address.

This is the only way to overcome license problems. [More in AWS ENI documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_ElasticNetworkInterfaces.html)

Comment: I will add a warning: If you have licenses on EC2, and you destroy that instance, make sure that you also don't destroy the ENI associated with that instance! If you do so, then you can kiss those license(s) goodbye!